# Import a DLL in QT with no .lib or .h

Tags: qt, dll

I can't find a proper answer on the Internet, so I'm coming to you. We gave to me a `.dll` file and I've got a `.xml` file that describe every function in this `.dll`.

Now I want to include this `.dll` but every answer that I'm finding on the Internet talk about `.lib` and `.h` , is there a way to add my `.dll` file to my project ?

Thank you.

Comment: You would like to load the symbols dynamically? Have you tried QLibraryLoader for thooat?

Comment: @FinalContest Can you give me more info about this ?

Comment: yes, answer submitted.

Comment: Evans, can you answer the original question though? Are you trying to dynamically load the dll or what are you using the xml for? Either way, whoever provides the dll to you should provide more information, i.e. they should tell you if it is meant to be dynamically loaded or they were supposed to generate the API header for you, etc.

Comment: @FinalContest Yes I think I will contact compagnies, and I can't answer you, I have no more info :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/dd142cccc7008c78ae74f3d02da402e2415becd2%3asrc/serialport/qtudev_p.h) you can find what I wrote for QtSerialPort to load the symbols dynamically for udev.

[This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QLibrary.html#details) is the core principle of the code:

```
QLibrary myLib("mylib");
typedef void (*MyPrototype)();
MyPrototype myFunction = (MyPrototype) myLib.resolve("mysymbol");
if (myFunction)
    myFunction();
```

If you need a "global" instance to be accessible from multiple places, you can also instantiate the `QLibrary` as follows:

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QLibrary, udevLibrary)
```

Comment: I try to implement your solution but I'm kinda lost, I guess "mylib" is the link to my .dll file, but what is MyPrototype ?

Comment: That is a function pointer variable, but you still need to provide more information.

Comment: What type of info ? Maybe we can chat about it, because i'm not sure chere to place your code and when to call it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use QLibrary to call functions dynamically. The following example calls a function from a shared library at runtime:

```
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QDebug>

typedef int (*call_func)(int arg1, int arg2);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLibrary library( "dynamic_library" );
    library.load();
    if( !library.isLoaded() )
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot load library.";
        return 0;
    }
    call_func func = (call_func)library.resolve( "function1" );
    if( func)
    {
        func( 1, 2 );
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It is not true that it should be defined like that in the library. QLibrary can load non-qt based dlls just fine, too.

Comment: OK, thanks. Another syntax error is the missing closing double quote after function1. Also, if you are at detecting errors, I would suggest to print out the error message, too.

Comment: `./dynamic_library` is not cross-platform AFAIK, whereas QLibrary is. I think `./` will not work on Windows.

Comment: @FinalContest If you put the library for example `dynamic_library.dll` in Windows or `dynamic_library.so` in Linux alongside the executable, it is fine.

Comment: I just checked, but `./` is not working on my Windows. Also, it is better to drop the `./` either way because then it will work from LD_LIBRARY_PATH, too, on Linux, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the `.xml` file and generate an `.h` file for it. You may also wish to generate a `.def` file. The `.def` file would be used to generate an import library, needed for the linker.

If you could show a complete sample of the xml file, it should be a simple matter to leverage Qt to produce the header and definition file.